# Aurora Serverless MySQL Gives "Index Column Size Too Large" Despite Proper Settings

Tags: mysql, aws-serverless, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm trying to add an index to an existing table as part of the upgrade process for Invision Community forums. The database is hosted in AWS Aurora Serverless, which has MySQL 5.6 compatibility. However, every time, I receive the error:

```
ERROR 1709 (HY000): Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.
```

Here are the details about the table and the schema:

```
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+
| Name          | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows  | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time | Update_time | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options     | Comment |
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+
| ibf_core_tags | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 36862 |            299 |    11026432 |               0 |     13189120 |   4194304 |          95183 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |     NULL | row_format=DYNAMIC |         |
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+
```

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| tag_id             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tag_aai_lookup     | char(32)     | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| tag_aap_lookup     | char(32)     | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| tag_meta_app       | varchar(200) | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| tag_meta_area      | varchar(200) | NO   |     |         |                |
| tag_meta_id        | int(10)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| tag_meta_parent_id | int(10)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| tag_member_id      | int(10)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| tag_added          | int(10)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| tag_prefix         | int(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| tag_text           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Default charset for the table is utf8mb4 and the `innodb_large_prefix` setting is `ON`.

The operation I'm trying to do is:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `ibf_core_tags` ADD KEY `tag_text` (`tag_text`(191));
```

I would think 191 * 4 = 764, which is less than the 767 byte value it says I'm exceeding. Is this a bug in Aurora Serverless? Is there a way around this issue? I've tried changing the table to MyISAM to add the index, but I actually get the same error when I try that.

Using a local install of MySQL 5.6, I was able to run this ALTER TABLE query on the same database, so I'm not sure why Aurora Serverless is any different.

I ended up trying this on a non-serverless Aurora instance and had that same issue.

Comment: Aurora is not InnoDB, it's a closed-source storage engine made by Amazon. Many InnoDB config options are ignored by Aurora.

Comment: I'm aware, but `innodb_large_prefix` is one of the options their documentation says it does not ignore, which is why I'm confused why this issue is occurring.

Comment: Does it work if you change tag_text to varchar(191) and then declare the index without trying to use index prefix syntax?

Comment: Ask the support team. Then post the answer here.

Comment: @BillKarwin That's a great idea. I tried that, after making sure there wouldn't be any data loss, and sure enough it worked. I'm kinda astounded. What will happen to the new index if I then resize the column itself to varchar(191)?

Comment: Actually, I was suggesting resizing the column to varchar(191) and then creating an index on that. But I'm glad it worked for you. I would guess that Aurora doesn't support index prefixes? I don't know. That's one of the problems with Aurora. They've changed a bunch of internals for the storage engine, but they're not very forthcoming with information about exactly what they've changed.

Comment: Sorry, I mispoke: I meant that I resized the column to 191 and then created an index on that. I was wondering what would happen if I then resized the column again to 255. If you don't specify an index prefix length, I'm fuzzy on what happens.

Comment: If you try to redefine the column size to 255, I expect the error will occur again, if the storage engine can't store an index for strings longer than 4 * 191 bytes. That's what happens on plain MySQL (i.e. not Aurora). I don't have an Aurora instance handy to test this.

Comment: Yup, that is what happened.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue with a Slim PHP project using Laravel for the DB connections. By default, AWS Aurora Serverless is using the file format of `Antelope` which defaults to the row format of `COMPACT`. We need a file format of `Barracuda` and a row format of `DYNAMIC` in order to allow large index key prefixes ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html)).

I created a custom Parameter Group and explicitly set the following parameters:

- `innodb_file_format` = `Barracuda`
- `innodb_file_per_table` = `1`
- `innodb_large_prefix` = `1`

These params are allowed to be set according to [AWS's Aurora Serverless documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.parameter-groups).

Setting these params didn't fix the issue by itself though. Tables were still being created with a row format of `COMPACT`. In the DB connection params I also had to set `'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC'` ([reference](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/migrations-and-table-options-row-format?page=0#reply=318711)). This syntax is for Laravel but hopefully it points others in the right direction as I just spent a whole afternoon figuring it out :)

Comment: I will try giving this a go in the near future and see if it fixes my problem, thanks!